# Сочетание согласованного и несогласованного определений

Tags: пунктуация, синтаксис, союзы, определения

Есть ли правило о сочетании согласованного и несогласованного определений в качестве однородных членов, соединённых одиночным сочинительным союзом?

Можно ли так написать:

*Давайте посчитаем все компьютерные игры, вышедшие в 2007-2012 годах и с оценкой выше 80 баллов по версии сайта Метакритик.*

1. Игры (определяемое слово).
2. Игры, ***вышедшие в 2007-2012 годах*** (согласованное распространённое определение).
3. Игры ***с оценкой выше 80 баллов по сайту Метакритик*** (несогласованное распространённое определение).

Вывод: Игры, *вышедшие в 2007-2012 годах* и *с оценкой выше 80 баллов по сайту Метакритик.*

Иными словами, имеются два морфологически разных однородных определения, которые связаны одиночным сочинительным соединительным союзом **И**.

Верный вывод? Стилистика и прочая бодяга меня не интересуют; важно то, можно ли в сочинённый ряд с одиночным соединительным союзом (без запятой перед ним) складывать однородные члены, выраженные разными частями речи.

Answer (score 1):

Если так написать, читатели не станут заниматься морфологическим разбором и анализировать определения на согласованность и однородность, а будут задаваться вопросами:

1) это одна общая группа игр с двумя признаками или две раздельных;

2) если две раздельных, то подсчитать их нужно все вместе или раздельно по группам?

Если первое, то правильнее выразиться так:

> ... игры с оценкой выше 80 баллов по версии сайта Метакритик из (числа)
>   вышедших в 2007-2012 годах.

Если же это две группы, то для однозначности слово "игры" нужно повторить и указать "вместе" ли "все" нужно подсчитывать.

Answer (score 1):

1) В принципе сочетание однородных согласованных и несогласованных определений, связанных союзом И, возможно, например: **Нас встретил мужчина стройный и приятной наружности**.  http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=108#pp108

2)  Можно привести такой пример: **В магазине было много книг,  напечатанных на качественной бумаге и с красочными иллюстрациями.**

3) Заданный пример: **Давайте посчитаем все компьютерные игры, вышедшие в 2007-2012 годах и с оценкой выше 80 баллов по версии сайта Метакритик.**

В этом случае названы два признака, по которому выбраны игры. Признаки разные, **но статус у них один: они обозначают заданные условия, поэтому являются сближенными** и в данном тексте однородными (сравнить: назовите все красные и круглые предметы на картинке). Соответственно,  союз И обязателен.

4) **Попробуем обозначить признаки как неоднородные без союза И**:

Давайте посчитаем все компьютерные игры, вышедшие в 2007-2012 годах  с оценкой выше 80 баллов по версии сайта Метакрити.

Получается некорректное управление: вышедшие с оценкой выше 80 баллов.